# How to change a state of a widget that is generated from list in flutter

Tags: flutter, setstate

My problem is simple. I was building a `ListTile` from the **list** of documents I get from firebase by iterating through the results. The `ListTile` contains a leading icon, a title, and a trailing favorite `IconButton`. The list tile shows perfectly as I want it to. But the problem arises when I try to change the color of the `IconButton` while a user taps on it. For some reason, the code I wrote isn't doing the trick. What i tried to do was to set the value of the `IconButton`'s color by a ternary which uses a class variable named `isFavorited`. What i wanted it to do is change the color of the `IconButton` when i tap on that same `IconButton`. Here is my code block:

```
// Builds a tile for each brought up names of taxistops
            if (retrievedData.isNotEmpty) {
              retrievedData.forEach((element) {
                if (element.contains(query) ||
                    element.contains(query.toUpperCase()) ||
                    element.contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
                  ListTile listTile = ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.local_taxi),
                    title: Text(element),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      icon: isFavorited
                          ? Icon(
                              Icons.star,
                              color: Colors.amber[400],
                            )
                          : Icon(Icons.star_border),
                      onPressed: () => {
                        setState(() {
                          isFavorited = true;
                        }),
                        addToFavorite()
                      },
                    ),
                    onTap: () => close(context, element),
                  );
                  searchedTiles.add(listTile);
                }
              });
            }
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you are adding the widget in the list you should preview it directly inside the widget father (ListView) so it can do the setState correctly and not inside a list you created as a data structure to store elements.
I think that's the issue if it still doesn't work I would need to see how you are showing the list.

Comment: How can i do that? After getting the list of documents from firebase, how can i make a `ListTile` for all of them and still be able to change the `IconButton`'s color `onTap`?

Comment: I just noticed that you only have one favourite value that means when you press the like button all of the items will change in the list with the value. You can create another statefull widget for the list tile and control the change of each tile in the new statefull widget. And I noticed in the code you are not given a color on the else value.